# What was my reply?

Tags: riddle, cipher

My friend sent me three texts asking me to solve a puzzle.
Can you shed some light on it?

Text 1:

> First you have to unlucky it
>   Then you have to transform it
>   But if you get some Gibberish by matching it
>   Just take one step down from it
>   Then you must say "I have found it"

Text 2:

> ZQKIV ZPPPK IVVV PZKKV ZZPQK PPKVK KIV ZZPPKKV YVV ZPZKVV PYIV ZZKK

Text 3:

> .. .. .. .. . . .. .. .. .. . .. .. .. . . .. .. .. . .. ..

I got it and replied to him.
What was my reply?

[Note : If you get the puzzle and found some tags missing or unnecessary feel free to add or remove them]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You replied:

> **I Have Found It**

First you have to [unlucky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triskaidekaphobia) it:

> Hints at a ROT13 transformation.
>
>  Taking Text 2:
>  `ZQKIV ZPPPK IVVV PZKKV ZZPQK PPKVK KIV ZZPPKKV YVV ZPZKVV PYIV ZZKK`
>
>  And applying ROT13 gives:
>  `MDXVI MCCCX VIII CMXXI MMCDX CCXIX XVI MMCCXXI LII MCMXII CLVI MMXX`

Then you have to transform it.

> The most striking thing is these are Roman numerals, so converting to decimal gives:
>   `1516  1310    8   921  2410   219  16    2221  52   1912  156 2020`

Using Text 3 as a guide to align the previous string, we get:

> `.. .. .. .. . . .. .. .. .. . .. .. .. . . .. .. .. . .. ..`
>  `15 16 13 10 8 9 21 24 10 21 9 16 22 21 5 2 19 12 15 6 20 20`

Treating this as letter indices:

> A = 1, Z = 26
>
>  we get:
>  `O  P  M  J H I  U  X  J  U I  P  V  U E B  S  L  O F  T  T`

But if you get some Gibberish by matching it
Just take one step down from it

> Applying ROT25 (one step down), we get:
>  `N  O  L  I G H  T  W  I  T H  O  U  T D A  R  K  N E  S  S`
>
>  which reads as:
>
>  **No Light Without Darkness**

Then you must say "I have found it", which is what you replied!

Comment: *Yeah you got it,*   
*Because steps were easy in it,*  
*And the next could be too if you know what is it*

Comment: Nice puzzle @prit.patel , I think I've cracked it.

Comment: *Yeah you cracked it, but you haven't got it, if you see what i asked in it, you will have to rewrite it*

Comment: @Phylyp Nice work!

Comment: Too much easy? As my first one? @Phylyp

Comment: It's good for a first one,  nicely layered (esp. text 3), with a twist as well. Week done, and we look forward to more.